# SVG: Is it possible to cut out a region?

Tags: css, svg

Using SVG, is it possible to cut out a region from a group?

For example, given the blue parent container below, is it possible to say "cut out from x=25% until x=75%", without modifying the child elements inside the group?

A is the initial state, B is what it would end up as:

[image]

Comment: SVG does not have a concept of reflow like HTML does, so no.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if there was a `<g transform="x">` that could do it that I was unaware of.

Comment: Sure but that means changing the child elements in the group which you said was not allowed. i.e. apply a transform to the elements you want and hide the ones you don't want to see.

Comment: I mean not changing the child attributes, only the parent `<g>`. E.g. I have a timeline, each child is a segment of time. I want to hide regions of the timeline whilst keeping `sum(visibleSegments)==100%` of `<g>`

Comment: I guess the essence of what I am asking is: Can you cut the middle of a `<rect>` out without changing its x/y width/height attributes.

Comment: sure but I don't see how you could move the rect labelled 4 without setting a transform on it.

Answer (score 1):

As commented @Robert Longson:

> SVG does not have a concept of reflow like HTML does, so no.

Maybe try to create the illusion of folding using SMIL animation commands which will move the rectangles 2, 3, 4 and hide the second and third rectangle under the first

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 416 250" >  
 <defs> 
     <!-- Define a rectangle pattern -->
    <rect id="child" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="184"  stroke="crimson" stroke-width="6" />
   
 </defs>  
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="410" height="196" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="6" />
        <!-- Clone rectangle copies -->
     <use id="r2" x="108" y="8" xlink:href="#child" fill="gold" > 

        <!-- Rectangle Collapse Animation -->
     <animate id="s_r2" attributeName="x" values="108;2" begin="start.click+0.1s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" /> 
        <!-- Rectangle Expansion Animation -->
     <animate id="e_r2" attributeName="x" values="2;108" begin="back.click"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
         
    </use>
               
       <use id="r3" x="210" y="8" xlink:href="#child" fill="purple" >
      <animate id="s_r3" attributeName="x" values="210;2" begin="start.click+0.1s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" /> 
         <animate id="e_r3" attributeName="x" values="2;210" begin="back.click"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
    </use>
    
    
      <use id="r4" x="312" y="8" xlink:href="#child" fill="white"  >
          <animate id="s_r4" attributeName="x" values="312;108" begin="start.click+0.1s"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
           <animate id="e_r4" attributeName="x" values="108;312" begin="back.click"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
    </use>
      
    <use id="r1" x="6" y="8" xlink:href="#child" fill="white" />  
  <!-- The button that starts the animation collapses the rectangles -->  
    <g id="start" transform="translate(-100 200)">
     <rect x="120" y="10" width="80" height="30" rx="15" fill="transparent" stroke="#B59964" />
   <text x="138" y="33" font-size="24" fill="#C75C5C" >Start </text>
 </g>   
     <!-- Button that starts the animation of the rectangles turning -->
        <g id="back" transform="translate(0 200)">
     <rect x="120" y="10" width="80" height="30" rx="15" fill="transparent" stroke="#B59964" />
   <text x="138" y="33" font-size="24" fill="#C75C5C" >Back </text>
 </g>  
</svg>
```